# How to avoid automatically saved drafts of a SMS created by an application?

Tags: android

My app creates a SMS the following way:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(new StringBuilder().append("sms:").append(number).toString()));
i.putExtra("sms_body", getSMS());
startActivity(i);
```

This opens the default application for sending SMS. Assumed this is the default Android Messaging app, is there a way to automatically discard the SMS when it is not sent?

When the user returns to my app pressing the back button I can search for the automatically saved draft and discard it. However this does not work if the home button is pressed and the user returns to home screen.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: You could see if the startActivity failed and handle the discarding right then and there?

Comment: I guess you need to directly query the sms provider and delete the draft

Comment: onActivityResult works for a user returning with the back button, but not when closing the app before returning to the parent activity. Seems like the only way to do it...